# How can I tell Cocoapods to inherit LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS from the current target?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cocoapods

In my project, we link against a few binary libraries that we keep under source control. We also use a Cocoapod which provides a library in binary form.

At the project level, we specify library search paths to our local libraries. When we add the binary Cocoapod to this target, resulting `xcconfig` file sets the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` config variable and conflicts with our project setting for this. We see this warning:

```
[!] The `MyProject [Debug]` target overrides the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Our workaround is to put the path to the Cocoapods library in our target search path and let it override the one from `xcconfig`.

To avoid overriding, we could put the `$(inherited)` flag in the `xcconfig` file, but then that means that we need to put the `xcconfig` into source control and reset it after running `pod install`.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Is there something we can set in the `Podfile` to add paths or the `$(inherited)` flag?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use post install hook to insert your own static library or framework which you don't install through pods.
https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install